# How do you prove friendship/relationship with person inviting you

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, canada, international-travel

How do you prove relationship with your friend who is inviting you to Canada in Canada visitor application?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is with a letter of invitation from the friend.  But notice that this is not required.  Special requirements exist for visiting family, but not friends: https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/supporting-documents.html